# OpenCV4Android class Mat: difference between width() and rows(), and that between height() and cols()?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, mat, android

In OpenCV4Android, what is the difference between the method `width()` and `rows()`; and what is the difference between the methods `height()` and `cols()` of the class `Mat`?

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#width()) does not say anything about these methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference between them. In general `width() == cols()` and `height() == rows()`;

In fact, the `width()` and `height()` methods internally  calls the `cols()` and `rows()` methods to get the value.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Could you tell me how you know that? I mean is there a place where I can see the code in OpenCV classes?

Comment: Hi, it is there in Mat.java class provided by the OpenCV Android sdk.Open this Mat.java file in any java IDE like android studio then you will definitely find it.